# Invers Function is measurable but Function not

Tags: real-analysis

Can we give an example to show that the measurability of the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ for every a does not imply that $f$ is a measurable function?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. I have edited your post to introduce TeX for better readability. Please check whether this edit is OK. To be taken seriously here, please state what you have done so far. Have you looked up the definition of a measurable function? How does it differ from the assumption in the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just take an injective non measureable function.

Answer (score 1):

Following Rene's idea, here's an explicit example:

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set.  Define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = 
x + 1_A(x) = \begin{cases}
x+1 & x \in A\\
x& x\notin A
\end{cases}
$$
This function is injective but non-measurable (why?).